# Can I revert a TFS work item?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I accidentally deleted a bunch of useful text from a TFS work item, using web-based TFS. Can I revert my changes? Or at least view the prior state? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can view all your changes in the History tab.
Just open the work item again in a browser and click History button next to Details.

P.S. TFS 2017.1

Comment: In my TFS, which is likely older, I also had to click "All Changes" after selecting "History". It defaults to "Discussion only" which is not helpful for me.